# getting distinct values from objects acording to one of its fields

Tags: c#

I have a List object in C# where item is the following class

```
    public class item
    {
        public string type{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
    }
```

how can i get a list of types, with distinct values.
If i have 3 items:

In this case:

```
item x1 = new item(){type="ABC",name="Thing1"};
item x2 = new item(){type="ZYX",name="Thing2"};
item x3 = new item(){type="ABC",name="Thing3"};
```

i would get a list with 2 values, ABC and ZYX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with LINQ:

```
List<string> types = source.Select(x => x.type)
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```